# Jquery set width of div to window then divide

Tags: jquery, width, divide

I have a site that has 3 panels it slides through. I want to set the background of each panel to be the window size so I am using:

```
var width1 = $(document).width(); 

var width2 = $(".nav").width(); 

var width_diff = width1 - width2 + "px";

document.getElementById('test').style.width = width_diff;
```

However I want to divide the width by the number of panels as the window size equals the total of them.

Many thanks.

Comment: I didn't fully understand your question. Could you please describe your situation and your goal more in details ? (Will your 3 panels fit all the page's width, and what does the "test" stand for ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change your current line to this:

```
var width_diff = (width1 - width2) / 3 + "px"
```